# Adjustable number input element?

Tags: numbers, interactive-ui

I am looking for examples of a ui element that allows users to modify a number  either by typing or "interacting" with the number (slide, drag, +/- etc.)

The specific use case is where a user will input her salary (4-5 figures) but then also explore what happens to a visualization if she "plays around" with that number.

I am aware of [Tangle](http://worrydream.com/Tangle/), but are there other "reactive" techniques/elements for this purpose around?

Answer (score 2):

I think Tydlig is a good example.

[demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xbXaKxxUomE)

in the app, you can drag numbers around and use them as variables.

[image]

in the example above, you first type 1 + 2 =, the app gives answer 3. Then, you drag 3 out of position to make it a variable. 
[image]

Now, if you change the first equation 1 + 2 = 3 so that the result is no longer 3, the other two equations' results will change accordingly.

You can also plot numbers related by equations. (y axis for variables and x axis for a constant), then you can change the x value using a slider and see how y values change accordingly.

[image]